# Error Message are not coming

Tags: 7, theming

I have create a template for user-register page

I have created a module under hook_form_alter as

```
if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {

            $form['account']['pass']['#type'] = 'password';
            $form['account']['pass']['#title'] = 'Password';
            $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = 'Email';
            $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Request Access';
             $form['#theme'] = 'user_register';

    }
```

**Edited:**

```
  function custom_user_register_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

        if($form_state['input']['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value'] == ''){  
            form_set_error('field_first_name', t('Email can not be empty'));
        }
          drupal_set_message($message, 'error');

     if($form_state['input']['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value'] == ''){
        form_set_error('field_last_name', 'Title cannot be "test"');
         drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
     }  

                return $form;
    }
```

And i have created a user-regiter.tpl.php file

under this i have code like this

```
 <?php print drupal_render($form['field_first_name']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

Which is working fine

Now when i submit form. it doesnt display error message . **But it is showing red border** in input box.

Why it is not showing error message . Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you're not showing the Drupal messages in your theme.  Take a look to ensure you have the following (somewhere, probably in your page.tpl.php file);

```
<?php print $messages; ?>
```

Note that you've made some other mistakes though (not related to your issue) - First, you should use `$form_state['values']` to gain the values when using `_validate()`; second, you can lose the two `drupal_set_message($message, 'error');` lines as they aren't doing anything?